# How do I retrieve a boolean value from my form and do a comparison in a view in Django?

Tags: python, django

Currently I am retrieving a value like this in my view:

```
is_service = request.POST.get('is_service', '')
```

I then want to check if this value is false and if it is to do something. Currently I have

```
if is_service == 0 : 
    Do Something
```

I have tried a lot of other variations such as `if is_service == False`, etc.

What is the proper syntax to do this comparison in the view

**Edit** Here is my is_service definition:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    ...
    is_service = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Django `form` or `modelForm` and give the `is_service` field a boolean type. Django will normalize the string that is supplied by the user into the correct python type.

### forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    is_service = forms.BooleanField()
```

### views.py

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            is_service = form.cleaned_data['is_service']

            if not is_service:
                # do something
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'some_view.html', {'form': form})
```

### some_view.html

```
<form action="/some_view/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought cleaned_data gets called when you do .is_valid. Why do you have to call it here?

Comment: Because is the only way to access the form data.